# Invalid URI reading XML file on Mono but works fine with Windows

Tags: c#, xml, mono

I am working on a c# project which needs to work on Windows and Linux (Mono) which when it starts up it reads some settings from an xml config file. On windows this is working fine but on Linux it is going wrong. It throwing an exception saying that it has an invalid URI but this can't be correct as it works fine on Windows.

I thought maybe it was due to the file getting corrupted in some way during the transfer so I removed the config file and retyped it manually but it is still coming up with the same error.

Below is the code that reads in the config file

```
public Dictionary<string, string> readConfig(string sectionName, bool soapService=false)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                XmlDocument configXml = new XmlDocument();
                string configPath = "";
                if (soapService)
                {
                    string applicationPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(null);
                    configPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, "config.xml");
                }
                else
                {
                    string applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
                    configPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, "config.xml");
                }
                configXml.Load(configPath);
                XmlNodeList options = configXml.SelectNodes(string.Format("/options/{0}", sectionName));
                XmlNodeList parameters = configXml.GetElementsByTagName("item");
                foreach (XmlNode option in options)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode setting in option)
                    {
                        string key = setting.Attributes["key"].Value;
                        string value = setting.Attributes["value"].Value;

                        config.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Config KeyNotFoundException: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            catch (XmlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Config XmlException: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Config Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            return config;
        }
```

The full exception is `Config Exception: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed`

Below is the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<options>
  <database>
    <item key="server" value="localhost" />
    <item key="database" value="emailserver" />
    <item key="username" value="myusername" />
    <item key="password" value="mypassword" />
    <item key="port" value="3306" />
    <item key="logFile" value="email_server.txt" />
  </database>
  <EmailServer>
    <item key="ip_address" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <item key="port" value="12345" />
  </EmailServer>
  <SmtpServer>
    <item key="ip_address" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <item key="port" value="25" />
  </SmtpServer>
  <SendMailSettings>
    <item key="smtp_server" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <item key="smtp_port" value="587" />
    <item key="smtp_useSSL" value="true" />
    <item key="smtp_username" value="myusername" />
    <item key="smtp_password" value="mypassword" />
    <item key="smtp_useAuthentication" value="true" />
  </SendMailSettings>
</options>
```

I don't understand why it is displaying this error.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
Below is the stack trace as requested

> StackTrace:   at System.Uri.Parse (UriKind kind, System.String
>   uriString) [0x00000] in :0   at System.Uri.ParseUri
>   (UriKind kind) [0x00000] in :0   at System.Uri..ctor
>   (System.String uriString, Boolean dontEscape) [0x00000] in :0   at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x00000]
>   in :0   at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri
>   (System.Uri baseUri, System.String relativeUri) [0x00000] in :0   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri (System.Uri
>   baseUri, System.String relativeUri) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String url,
>   System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor (System.String url,
>   System.Xml.XmlNameTable nt) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at BoardiesITSolutions.Config.readConfig
>   (System.String sectionName, Boolean soapService) [0x00000] in
>   :0

Comment: @SLaks I've added the strack trace to the question

Comment: Please post the stack trace with newlines. (wrap it in `<pre>` tags)

Comment: What is the value of `configPath`?

Comment: The config path is /home/bits/EmailServer/config.xml which is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem, I don't understand why this is the problem I'm guessing it must be a bug in Mono as it works fine in Windows.

Even though the following code works fine in Windows for some reason in Mono it throws that exception even though it does get the correct path. If I remove that code and just change the configPath to be `"config.xml"` then it works fine.

```
string applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
configPath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, "config.xml");
```